# Two functions running at same time

Tags: python-3.x

I was working on a house security project, but I wanted to run a function at the same time as another. When I turn On security for AC in the code below, and then switch to MS, I want the AC to stay running if I have a loop in the sec_MS(1), but not affect the  MS's program. If you didn't understand check the code below:

```
##Library importing:
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import tkSimpleDialog


##Variables:
btnchange = "Off"
btn2change = "AC"
AC_Status = "Off"
MS_Status = "Off"


##Making window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Home Security")
root.geometry("450x450")


##Homesecurity Label:
label = tk.Label(root, text="\n\n\nHome Security:")
label.config(font=("Courier", 44))
label.pack()


##Trn MC-On/Off func: 
def sec_MS(OO1):
  if (OO1 == 1):
    print("MS Security On...")

    btnchange = "On"



  if (OO1 == 0):
    print("MS Security Off...")

    btnchange = "Off"


##Trn AHC-On/Off func:  
def sec_AC(OO2):
  if (OO2 == 1):
    print("AC Security On...")

    btnchange = "On"



  if (OO2 == 0):
    print("AC Security Off...")

    btnchange = "Off"


##Trn off all scrty whn runned: 
sec_AC(0)
sec_MS(0)


##def btn-cmd = trn scrty on/off:
def secon_off():
  if btn["text"] == "Off":
    btnchange = "On"
    if btn2["text"] == "AC":
      sec_AC(1)

    if btn2["text"] == "MS":
      sec_MS(1)

  if btn["text"] == "On":
    btnchange = "Off"
    if btn2["text"] == "AC":
      sec_AC(0)

    if btn2["text"] == "MS":
      sec_MS(0)


  btn["text"] = btnchange


##def btn-cmd = swtch scrty type:  
def WSEC():
  global AC_Status
  global MS_Status
  if btn2["text"] == "AC":
    AC_Status = btn["text"]
    btn["text"] = MS_Status
    btn2change = "MS"
    if btn["text"] == "On":
      sec_MS(1)
    if btn["text"] == "Off":
      sec_MS(0)
  if btn2["text"] == "MS":
    MS_Status = btn["text"]
    btn["text"] = AC_Status
    btn2change = "AC"
    if btn["text"] == "Off":
      sec_AC(0)
    if btn["text"] == "On":
      sec_AC(1)
  btn2["text"] = btn2change


##Button/BtnFont:
helv23 = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=23)
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="AC", width=27, command=WSEC)
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Off", width=27, command=secon_off)
btn2["font"] = helv23
btn["font"] = helv23
btn2.pack()
btn.pack()


##Run the mainloop:
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider marking it as accepted! :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the `threading` module:

```
from threading Import Thread

t = Thread(target=func_id_like_to_run, args=(args, for, loop))
t.start()
... 
# Do other stuff
```

`t.start()` will execute the function `func_id_like_to_run()` with all args passed in the `args` parameter (optional; if your function doesnt take args, simply ignore that parameter) in a separate thread.

Keep in mind that this is not the same as using multiple cores! This doesn't work in python using `threading`, due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: `Thank_You.start()`